# How to pass QStandardItemModel from a function?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qabstractitemmodel, qstandarditemmodel

To display some data in `QTableView`, I use a function to compute the `QStandardItemModel` and sent it back to the calling function.

Function Call:

```
QStandardItemModel MyModel = computeMyModel();
ui->tV->setModel(&MyModel);
```

Called Function

```
QStandardItemModel computeMyModel()
{
    QStandardItemModel newModel;
    //........... Steps to compute newModel
    return newModel;
}
```

I get the following error when I try to run the code.

```
error C2248: 'QStandardItemModel::QStandardItemModel' : cannot access private member declared in class 'QStandardItemModel'
```

How to solve this problem?(How to successfully pass the myModel from one function to another without call by refernce?)

Constraints:

1. I have to compute the model in `computeMyModel()` function only.
2. I don't like to pass a model from the calling function to the `computeMyModel()` through call by   reference.

Comment: QStandardItemModel inherits from QObject, so you can not use its copy constructor (marked as private in QObject). Allocate it on the heap and pass it by pointer to your functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
QStandardItemModel* computeMyModel()
{
    int counter = 0;
    QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            counter++;
            QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(QString::number(counter));
            model->setItem(i,j,item);
        }
    return model;
}
```

Using:

```
QStandardItemModel *model = computeMyModel();

ui->tableView->setModel(model);
```

###### Update

No. It will be normal, because you allocate memory and return a pointer, your pointer has this memory address and it will have it until something deletes it. To prove this, see this code snippet. As you can see, you allocate memory in the function, return a pointer, set data using this pointer and call `setModel`. It compiles and works.

Function:

```
QStandardItemModel* computeMyModel()
{
    QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel;
    return model;
}
```

Using

```
int counter = 0;
QStandardItemModel *model = computeMyModel();

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {
        counter++;
        QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(QString::number(counter));
        model->setItem(i,j,item);
    }
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to achieve this is by passing a model created before hand and manipulating it through a reference.

It's not possible to return a `QStandardItemModel` because it's inaccessible, and sending back a pointer doesn't work.

Function:

```
void computeMyModel(QStandardItemModel& model)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
       for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
       {
          counter++;
          QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(QString::number(counter));
          model.setItem(i,j,item);
       }
}
```

Using:

```
QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel(0, 0, this);
computeMyModel(*model);
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
```